# Is it possible to have glmulti consider only select intaractions in all subsets model selection?

Tags: r, glm, consensus

I have been using the package [glmulti](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/glmulti.pdf) to run an all subsets model selection procedure. I have a large data set and my global model contains 7 candidate predictors. The issue is that I would like to consider just a single interaction between two of my main predictors. When I include an interaction term in the global model function, glmulti ignores it when I use 'level = 1' designating only main effects considered. Does anyone have a way that I can get the procedure to consider main effects and a single interaction?

Here is a small sample:

> GlobalModel
>
> rttdfit<- glm(ROCK~AREA+DRATIO+ELEV+SECC+BLDGD+MAXD*CLIM+I(CLIM^2),data=rttd,family=binomial(link="logit"))
>
> Allsubsets selection
>
> rttdASMS<-glmulti(rttdfit, confsetsize = 5, crit = "aic", level = 1, family = binomial("logit"))
>
> weightable(rttdASMS)

Comment: please add a small example

Comment: Sure! See below :)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching around regarding this question and found a link here that may help future readers:

https://vcalcagnoresearch.wordpress.com/package-glmulti/